# Which demo applications from Apple are good examples on usage of OpenGL ES on iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Besides CrashLanding, are there any other good example apps with source code?

Answer (score 3):

You should google for "Touch Fighter", it was released on WWDC, so I can't provide direct links to code, but you should google around, that's like Crash Landing on Steroids. I think Crash Landing had some leaks and bad practices in general.

If what you're looking for is the Texture2D class , the same class is located in cocos2d as stated before.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an opinion, but Crash Landing is a mess. There is some decent 2D OpenGL code in the [Cocos 2D engine](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/source/browse/). I find the sources very interesting.

Comment: I don't understand why Crashlanding hasn't been redone correctly. It was very nice to have a small app that exercised so many hardware features. It was easy to poke at it and learn the system.

Comment: Exactly. When I was starting I was very happy for CL too, but a decently written and maintained sample code would have made such a difference.